# How can I send GA4 events from apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I tried to call it like that, but got an error.

How can I make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you obviously didn't define the dataLayer. You commented it out. But you also didn't load the gtag library.

App script is executed in Node? I'm not very confident gtag.js is Node-friendly. And even if it is, many dimensions will most definitely suffer.

The [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) should be more appropriate for the backend. Oh and there's an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga4-mp) for it. That is, if npm is even viable in app script.

Or try using the [server-side GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side). It's default publishing implies an app script too, but it may want its own app script instance rather than sharing it with your code.